# Classical vs. modified Gram-Schmidt

Tags: matrix-factorization

It is often said that modified Gram-Schmidt is more robust with respect to rounding errors than classical Gram-Schmidt, but it is very hard to find a good explanation / example of why this is so. Can anyone provide such an explanation / example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what happens if you apply modified / classical Gram-Schmidt to the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \varepsilon & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \varepsilon \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\varepsilon \ll 1$.

The two algorithms agree on the first and second column and produce a $Q$ factor whose entries are given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & * \\
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & * \\
0 & 1 & * \\
0 & 0 & * \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
if we assume finite machine arithmetic with precision $\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach}$ and restrict ourselves to order-of-magnitude estimates. The first two entries in the second column may be explained by noting that $\tilde q_2 := a_2 - q_1^T a_2 \, q_1$ would set the first two entries of $\tilde q_2$ to zero in exact arithmetic, but rounding errors will make them $\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach})$ and normalising $\tilde q_2$ will lead to the values quoted above.

Classical Gram-Schmidt now computes the last column as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
0 & 1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The first two entries in the last column can be derived as above, and the third entry follows from $q_2^T \, a_3 = \mathcal{O}\bigl(\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1}\bigr)$ which yields $(\tilde q_3)_3 = \mathcal{O}\bigl(\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1}\bigr)$ and hence $(\tilde q_3)_3 = \mathcal{O}\bigl(\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-2}\bigr)$ after normalisation. We observe that if $\varepsilon = 10^{-8}$ and $\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} = 10^{-16}$, then the first column of $Q$ is orthogonal to the other two up to an error of about $\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} = 10^{-8}$, while the second and third column are orthogonal up to an error of $\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-2} = 1$, i.e. they are not orthogonal at all.

In contrast, the modified Gram-Schmidt algorithm leads to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
0 & 1 & \varepsilon_\mathrm{mach}^2 \, \varepsilon^{-2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since after projecting out the component in the first direction, the temporary vector $\tilde q_3^{(1)}$ is given by
$$
\tilde q_3^{(1)}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach} \, \varepsilon^{-1} \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
such that $q_2^T \tilde q_3^{(1)} = \mathcal{O}\bigl(\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach}^2 \, \varepsilon^{-1}\bigr)$.
With the values given above, we now have that the second and third column are orthogonal up to an error $\varepsilon_\mathrm{mach}^2 \, \varepsilon^{-2} = 10^{-16}$.

Comment: You can select your answer